# Prove that the equation $u^a - u^b = n!$ has finitely many solutions $(a,b,n)$ in positive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> (China TST 2004 Day 1). Let $u$ be a fixed integer. Prove that the equation $u^a - u^b = n!$ has finitely many solutions $(a,b,n)$ in positive integers. [Here](https://imomath.com/othercomp/Chn/ChnTST04.pdf) is the original source of the problem.

> Note: it's possible one has to additionally assume that $u\neq -1$. If it turns out that the claim is false for some $u\neq -1$, then just assume $u$ must be positive for convenience.

For a positive integer k and prime p, let $v_p(k)$ denote the highest exponent of p dividing k. If $u=0,1$, there are no solutions so assume $u\neq 0,1$. If $u=-1$, then $u^a - u^b$ can only take on the values $0, 2,$ and $-2$. But $2$ can be obtained infinitely many times, namely whenever a is even and b is odd, so it seems we need to assume $u\neq -1$. First consider the case when $u > 1$. Then $a > b$ clearly, so $u^b$ must divide $n!$. Also, $u^{a-b}-1 \ge 1$ is coprime to $u$ and divides $n!$. Equality only holds when $u=2$ and $a=b+1$. But in that case, we have $2^b = n!$, which only holds for $b=1$ as $n!$ is divisible by $3$ for $n\ge 1$. Since we're only interested in showing the given equation has finitely many solutions, we may as well assume $u^{a-b}-1 > 1$ so that it has a prime factor. I know that for any prime p, $v_p(n!) = \sum_{i\ge 1}\lfloor n/p^i\rfloor$. In particular, if we let $p$ be a prime dividing $u$ with $v_p(u) = k$, then from above, $v_p(n!) = kb$.  $n!$ grows faster than $u^n$ as $n\to\infty$ for any integer u. Clearly we cannot have $a = b,$ so it could be useful to consider when $a<b$ and when $a > b$ separately. It could be useful to use inequalities and show that when either $a$ or $b$ or $n$ exceed a certain bound, there are no more solutions. I know a fairly nontrivial fact that the last nonzero digit of $n!$ actually forms a nonperiodic sequence, though that's likely not useful for this problem. I'm also unsure whether it'll be useful to consider orders of powers of primes.

Comment: Have you tried figuring out how to express $n! = 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}3^{a_3}..... p_k^{a_k}$ yet.  For instance $10! = 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10=2.4.6.8.10.3.5.7.9=2^5.2.3.4.5.3.5.7.9=2^{5+2}.3.2.5.3.5.7.9=2^{5+2+1}.3.5.3.5.7.9=2^{5+2+1}3^{2}.5.5.7.3=2^{5+2+1}3^{2+1}5^2.7$.

Comment: Related [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h55883p346573)

Comment: @Sil Interestingly, that AoPS thread says the problem is from the same source as what the OP stated, but the although the OP provided link provided has the question starting with "Let $u$ be a fixed integer", the thread's question starts with "Let $u$ be a fixed *positive* integer" (with the rest of the question also being a bit different, e.g., using $\alpha$ and $\beta$ instead of $a$ and $b$). I wonder if that was a question fix that was perhaps added later because, as the OP has noted, the problem is not true for $u = -1$. Also, note the same question is also being asked, but with no ...

Comment: @Sil (cont.) answers, at the AoPS threads [$u^{a}-u^{b}=n!$ has finitely many solutions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1845576p12424547) and [Old and nice](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1287902p6800176), with the first one also being from the same problem set, and it *not* requiring $u$ to be positive, while the second one uses different variables, but also specifying the value, $b$ in this case, to just be an integer.

Comment: @user33096 FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24u%5Ea-u%5Eb%3Dn!%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Afinitely%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integers&p=1), in addition to finding the AoPS thread Sil mentioned, as well as the other $2$ related AoPS threads, there's also the specific question for $u = 2$, with it asking for all solutions here, at [Finding every triplet $(n,a,b)$ such that $n!=2^a-2^b$](/q/919173).

Comment: @JohnOmielan That is an interesting observation, it might be that organizers missed this, but I think it is likely that whoever translated and typed the "official" source to LaTeX simply made a mistake and omit the word "positive" (since the original was in Chinese and typeset to LaTeX by someone else later, the page contains typeset TST's from 1986 too...). I guess we would have to see the original to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a good start, including suggesting possibly using the orders of the powers of primes. Actually, the solution below uses the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of a prime.

As [Sil's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592498/prove-that-the-equation-ua-ub-n-has-finitely-many-solutions-a-b-n-i#comment9670893_4592498) indicates, the AoPS thread [Chinese factorial equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h55883p346573) references the same problem, with that thread providing several solutions having varying degrees of validity. I'm adapting (including making a few minor corrections) and expanding on the approach used in [Post #$12$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h55883p12042805).

For any $u \gt 1$, rewrite the equation as

$$n! = u^b(u^m - 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where $m = a - b \gt 0$. Next, note there's at most one solution for any fixed $n$ since, for each prime factor $q$ of $u$, we require $b = \frac{\nu_q(n!)}{\nu_q(u)}$. If just one integral value of $b$ works in all cases, then $a$ would be uniquely determined from \eqref{eq1A} based on $b$ and $n$, with there then being just one solution if $a$ is an integer. Thus, it's sufficient to show that only finitely many $n$ are solutions, with this answer doing this by proving that $n$ is bounded above.

Consider any prime $p$ which doesn't divide $u$, with $d$ being the multiplicative order of $u$ modulo $p$, i.e., $d = \operatorname{ord}_p(u)$. For any $n$ at least as large as the smallest prime factor of $u$ (so $b \gt 0$), and also with $n \ge p$, we have $p \mid n! \; \to \; p \mid u^m - 1$, so $d \mid m$. Since $u^m = \left(u^{d}\right)^{m/d}$, then by the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma),

$$\nu_p(u^m-1) = \nu_p(u^d-1) + \nu_p\left(\frac{m}{d}\right) \le \nu_p(u^d-1) + \log_p\left(\frac{m}{d}\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

With the constant

$$c_1 = \nu_p(u^d-1) - \log_p(d) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

as well as using $\log_p\left(\frac{m}{d}\right) = \log_p(m) - \log_p(d)$, we get from \eqref{eq2A} that

$$\nu_p(u^m-1) \le \log_p(m) + c_1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Next, [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) gives that

$$\nu_p(u^m-1) = \nu_p(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor \gt \frac{n}{p} - 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Combining \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq5A} results in

$$\log_p(m) + c_1 \gt \frac{n}{p} - 1 \; \; \; \to \; \; \; m \gt p^{\frac{n}{p} - c_2} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

where $c_2 = c_1 + 1$. We then get

$$n^n \gt n! = u^b(u^m - 1) \gt u^m \gt u^{p^{\frac{n}{p} - c_2}} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Taking the natural logarithm of each side gives

$$n\ln(n) \gt p^{\frac{n}{p} - c_2}\ln(u) \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

However, this can be true for at most a finite number of $n$ since the left side is less than a polynomial of $n$ (e.g., $n^2$), but the right side is a growing exponential function in $n$.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, are there still only finitely many solutions when $u< -1$?

Comment: @user33096 You're welcome. Regarding the case where $u \lt -1$, let $u = -v$ so $v \gt 1$. Then depending on the parity of $a$ and $b$, we have $u^a - u^b$ becoming one of $v^a + v^b$, $v^a - v^b$, $-v^a + v^b$ and $-v^a - v^b$. The second & third cases are basically the same as in my solution, while the fourth one has no solution. With the first one, if $a = b$, then we have $2v^a$ which has a finite # of solutions since for any odd prime $p \nmid v$, there's no solutions when $n \ge p$. Otherwise, WLOG, have $b \lt a$. Then $n!=v^b(v^m+1)$. Then basically proceed as I did earlier. ...

Comment: @user33096 In particular, for any odd prime $p \nmid v$, we now have $v^m \equiv -1\pmod{p} \; \to \; v^{2m} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Since $v^{2m}-1=(v^m+1)(v^m-1)$, then $p \nmid v^m - 1$, so $\nu_p(v^m+1) = \nu_p(v^{2m}-1)$. Thus, continue similarly as I did, replacing $m$ with $2m$ in most cases, to end up with a similar conclusion at the end.

Comment: Would you mind joining [my chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141092/user33096s-chat-room) and answering some hopefully quick questions I have?